# Is it possible to extend Flask-restless to add new routes?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restless

I am currently developing a REST API using Flask, Flask-sqlalchemy and flask-restless.

I have a User model and a Category model. A user can have many categories and a category belongs to only one user (one-to-many relationship). The relationship is set up in the sqlalchemy model.

I am using flask-restless to create the api. For instance, I have the following line to create the User api:

```
manager.create_api('User', collection_name='users', methods=['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE'])
```

When I do a GET request or POST request on /api/users, everything works fine.

When I do a GET request on /api/users/3/categories, it works too.

However, I am not able to do a POST request on /api/users/3/categories and get

Status Code: 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED , Allow: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET

Apparently, only OPTIONS, HEAD and GET requests are allowed but when creating the api, I did include POST.

Do you guys have any idea what the problem is? Or how to extend the api to allow for the POST method in flask-restless?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new categories to an existing user you should send a PUT/PATCH request to:

```
/api/users/3
```

with the request data looking like this:

```
{ "categories":
  {
    "add": [ {"field1": "val1", "field2": "val2"} ]
  }
}
```